# Changeing attributevalue using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Is there a faster way to make the selection of the "bnt" field and the value change in the "BUERO" field?

```
import time
start= time.time()
fldname = "BUERO" #Feldname, das die neuen Werte bekommt
newValue = 'eeJu!?'
myLyr =  iface.activeLayer() #aktueller Layer, der als Quelle genutzt wird
qry = "bnt = 'A11'"
mySel = myLyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(qry))

with edit(myLyr):
    for f in mySel:
        f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex(fldname), newValue)
        myLyr.updateFeature(f)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fast. Create a dictionary of `{feature id: {fieldindex: new value}}` and change the values with `layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues`.

This will modify the values without an edit session so backup your data first, or add an edit session to the code.

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer() #Start a timer

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("7k_multipart_polygons")[0]
fieldname = "kategori"

qry = f"\"{fieldname}\" =  'Vattenyta'" #All features where "kategori"='Vattenyta'
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(qry)
selection = layer.getFeatures(request)
selected_features =  [f for f in selection] #List the selected features
print(f"Features to modify: {len(selected_features)}")

fieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname)
attributemap = {} 

for feature in selected_features:
    attributemap[feature.id()] = {fieldindex:'BUERO'}
    #Add an entry to the attributemapdictionary of
    #  feature id : {fieldindex: new value}
    #  for example 1: {2: 'BUERO'}.
    #  Which means, feature with id 1, should in field 2 get value BUERO

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time

print(f"Code finished in {round(elapsed, 2)} s.")

Features to modify: 3825
Code finished in 0.47 s.
```

[image]

Comment: thx once more for your superior code

Comment: Is it possible to perform an arithmetic operation like Field1 * Field2 #  for example 1: {2: 'BUERO'}. #  for example 1: {2: 'Fied1'*'Fiedl2'}.