# Formatting of attribute map for changeAttributeValues method using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, geopackage, field-mapping, qgsvectorlayer

I have a PyQGIS script being run from within QGIS that updates attribute values in a GeoPackage, based on a mapping. It currently iterates through fields and features one by one, updating the values using `QgsVectorLayer.changeAttributeValue`.

This seems inefficient, particularly if there are many features. I'm looking to update it to use `QgsVectorDataProvider.changeAttributeValues`: https://qgis.github.io/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsVectorDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider.changeAttributeValues

The `changeAttributeValues` method takes as a parameter "attr_map (object) – a map containing changed attributes". Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't set out the format of the map, and a Google search hasn't yielded any useful information.

The aim is to update the code to create the attribute map, and then run one operation using `changeAttributeValues` to update all changes at once. I am specifically looking for the format of the attribute map, though code is of course welcome.

The dummy existing code is as follows:

```py
outfile = "c:/temp/output.gpkg"

oldFieldNames = ["oldField1", "oldField2", "oldField3"]
newFieldNames = ["newField1", "newField2", "newField3"]
mapping = [
    {0: "orange", 1: "apple", 2: "pineapple"},
    {0: "red", 1: "yellow", 2: "green", 3: "blue"},
    {0: "dog", 1: "cat", 2: "goat", 3: "cow", 4: "fish"},
]

vl = QgsVectorLayer(outfile, 'temp', 'ogr') 
pr = vl.dataProvider()

for i in range(len(oldFieldNames)):
    newFieldIndex = pr.fieldNameIndex(newFieldNames[i])
    with edit(vl):
        for feature in vl.getFeatures():
            vl.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), newFieldIndex, mapping[i][feature[oldFieldNames[i]]])
```

If the initial layer attributes are as follows:

| fid | oldField1 | oldField2 | oldField3 | newField1 | newField2 | newField3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |

then the final result after mapping should be:

| fid | oldField1 | oldField2 | oldField3 | newField1 | newField2 | newField3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 | orange | blue | fish |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | apple | green | cow |

As an aside, I have found quite regularly with the QGIS Python API documentation, that there is not enough detail to know the exact format of parameters required for some methods.

Comment: Not much help but you can look through tests in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?q=changeAttributeValues to see how methods are used there.

Comment: The C++ documentation gives sometimes more hints : https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a99a5d01c33c1cadb7ae9209b68cd8743 & https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsfeature_8h.html#a6d7973b8c9854def3e1d7f8c49a3851b

Comment: I'm no expert but when I have used it [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458202/changeing-attributevalue-using-pyqgis/458213#458213), it is a dictionary of dictionaries: {`feature_id: {field_index:new value}, ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BERA says, the attribute map is a dictionary of dictionaries, with the first key as the feature ID, and the second key as the field index.

e.g.

```py
attrMap = {
    featureId1: {fieldIndex1: value1, fieldIndex2: value2, fieldIndex3: value3}, 
    featureId2: {fieldIndex1: value4, fieldIndex2: value5}, 
    ...}
```

Updated code using `changeAttributeValues` (there may be more efficient ways of iterating):

```py
outfile = "c:/temp/output.gpkg"

oldFieldNames = ["oldField1", "oldField2", "oldField3"]
newFieldNames = ["newField1", "newField2", "newField3"]
mapping = [
    {0: "orange", 1: "apple", 2: "pineapple"},
    {0: "red", 1: "yellow", 2: "green", 3: "blue"},
    {0: "dog", 1: "cat", 2: "goat", 3: "cow", 4: "fish"},
]

vl = QgsVectorLayer(outfile, 'temp', 'ogr') 
pr = vl.dataProvider()

attrMap = {}
newFieldIndices = []
for i in range(len(newFieldNames)):
    newFieldIndices.append(pr.fieldNameIndex(newFieldNames[i]))

for feature in vl.getFeatures():
    featureAttrMap = {}
    for i in range(len(oldFieldNames)):
        featureAttrMap[newFieldIndices[i]] = mapping[i][feature[oldFieldNames[i]]]
    attrMap[feature.id()] = featureAttrMap

# print(attrMap)
pr.changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
```

The attrMap data for the example above is:

```py
attrMap = {
    1: {4: 'orange', 5: 'blue', 6: 'fish'}, 
    2: {4: 'apple', 5: 'green', 6: 'cow'}
}
```